# Can we debug release version of Adobe air application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

Are there any tools to debug release version of abode air app like ollydbg to windows applications which can break and run step on action script byte code and see AVM classes, stacks and registers? If yes, can you explain how? Thank you.

Comment: I dont think so, but, you may decompile the version of the installed app and try to get it to work, but it is not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug an swf or air app, the best you'll get is [Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/).  You do need to enable advanced realtime telemetry.  See [Getting Started with Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) by Thibault Imbert for more info.

Alternatively, if you've compiled in the relevant hooks, you should try [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/).